# How to create systemVerilog wrapper for vhdl DUT?

Tags: vhdl, wrapper, system-verilog, verification, uvm

This is simple VHDL design for flipflop. Please show me how to import vhdl file to systemverilog so i can do verification using UVM. If there is better way then wrapper please tell me. I am using Questa 10.4d.

```
library ieee;
use ieee. std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee. std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee. std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity flipflop is
    port(D, Clock : in  std_logic;
         Q : out  std_logic);
end flipflop;

architecture behavioral of flipflop is
begin
  process(CLOCK)
  begin
    if(CLOCK='1' and CLOCK'EVENT) then
      Q<=D;
    end if;
  end process;
end behavioral;
```

Comment: Depending what you mean by a "better way" you might consider keeping it pure VHDL and using the OSVVM library www.osvvm.org for advanced verification techniques. Works with several simulators including open-source ghdl ("ghdl-updates" at sourceforge)

Answer (score 3):

Questa lets you import VHDL entities without creating a wrapper. Check the user manual for mixed language simulation and look at the examples in *questadir*/examples/mixedlang/sv_vhdl_param